# extract 2D from 3D data using squeeze

Tags: matlab, try-catch, spectrum

I have a time series of sea surface elevation Z(201x151x4200) where 4200 are number of time values and 201x151 is the xy grid.  Many Z-values, especially the fringe values, have Nans, and I want to test if I can interpolate those values.  I have tested them in the past as follows on matlab:

```
z1=squeeze(Z(1,1,:))/1000;
z2=squeeze(Z(1,10,:))/1000;
z3=squeeze(Z(1,20,:))/1000;
z4=squeeze(Z(1,30,:))/1000;

z1(isnan(z1)) = interp1(find(~isnan(z1)),z1(~isnan(z1)), find(isnan(z1)),'spline');
z2(isnan(z2)) = interp1(find(~isnan(z2)),z2(~isnan(z2)), find(isnan(z2)),'spline');
z3(isnan(z3)) = interp1(find(~isnan(z3)),z3(~isnan(z3)), find(isnan(z3)),'spline');
z4(isnan(z4)) = interp1(find(~isnan(z4)),z4(~isnan(z4)), find(isnan(z4)),'spline');
```

then I would just manually choose which ones can be interpolated in order to obtain an average spectrum using periodogram.  I would like to not have to do this manually, but in some kind of try and catch loop.  Is this possible after squeezing Z into 2D?

Comment: I didn't quite get what you do manually. In any case, you can put the above in a `for`-loop =P

Answer (score 0):

convert your 3D matrix to a cell array using `num2cell`, and apply your `interp1` function to each element of the cell by calling `cellfun`. the following two-liner fills those missing data by calling interp1 for all points using only the non-nan data points. The non-nan values stay the same.

```
% create a testing data
a=rand(10,20,30);
a(randi(numel(a),30))=nan;

% convert the 3D array into a 2D cell array
b=num2cell(a,3);

% interp every element using only the non-nan elements
% non-nan elements stay unchanged
a2=cellfun(@(x) interp1(find(~isnan(x)),squeeze(x(~isnan(x))), 1:numel(x),'spline'),b,'uni',false);
```

Comment: I think using a `for` loop would be advantageous, because it does not require to copy the data (create a cell array).

Comment: Yes FangQ, thankyou that works, but as I said, the interp1 is a test.  Some cells will pass and some fail.  I want to catch and store the ones that pass.  Any ideas?